# Merge 2 different arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge

I would like merge 2 arrays with different data inside.

Here's the first array :

```
[
 [Wed, 30 Mar 2016, 2],
 [Fri, 01 Apr 2016, 1],
 [Sat, 02 Apr 2016, 1],
 [Sun, 03 Apr 2016, 1]
]
```

And here is the second array :

```
[
 Sun, 27 Mar 2016,
 Mon, 28 Mar 2016,
 Tue, 29 Mar 2016,
 Wed, 30 Mar 2016,
 Thu, 31 Mar 2016,
 Fri, 01 Apr 2016,
 Sat, 02 Apr 2016,
 Sun, 03 Apr 2016
]
```

Result i would like :

```
[
 Sun, 27 Mar 2016=>0,
 Mon, 28 Mar 2016=>0,
 Tue, 29 Mar 2016=>0,
 Wed, 30 Mar 2016=>2,
 Thu, 31 Mar 2016=>0,
 Fri, 01 Apr 2016=>1,
 Sat, 02 Apr 2016=>0,
 Sun, 03 Apr 2016=>1
]
```

And finally, this is the code for have 2 arrays

```
    @last_7_days = Statistic.where("date(created_at) > ?", 7.days.ago).group("date(created_at)").count
    @last_days = Date.today.downto(Date.today - 7.days).reverse_each.collect{|m| m}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The structure of the arrays, and the expected result are not clear.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't post valid Ruby code? What should your expected result be - an array (with one-pair hash elements!?) or simply a hash?

Comment: @cremno ok, i've added the ruby code.

Comment: You code examples aren't valid Ruby.

Comment: The dates are all presumably strings, so they needed to be within single or double quotes.  Your hash should be within braces (`{}`) not brackets (`[]`). The value of the penultimate key of the hash should be `1`, not zero. Please edit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland strangely he's not returning the value but the date. I've added "to_a" for have an array. But your other message he work fine ! thank you

Comment: Your reluctance to edit your question accounts for the piling-up of downvotes and votes to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [
  ["Wed, 30 Mar 2016", 2],
  ["Fri, 01 Apr 2016", 1],
  ["Sat, 02 Apr 2016", 1],
  ["Sun, 03 Apr 2016", 1]
]

b = [
  "Sun, 27 Mar 2016",
  "Mon, 28 Mar 2016",
  "Tue, 29 Mar 2016",
  "Wed, 30 Mar 2016",
  "Thu, 31 Mar 2016",
  "Fri, 01 Apr 2016",
  "Sat, 02 Apr 2016",
  "Sun, 03 Apr 2016"
]

Hash[b.map { |s| [s,0] }].merge(Hash[a])
  #=> {"Sun, 27 Mar 2016"=>O,
  "Mon, 28 Mar 2016"=>O,
  "Tue, 29 Mar 2016"=>O,
  "Wed, 30 Mar 2016"=>2,
  "Thu, 31 Mar 2016"=>O,
  "Fri, 01 Apr 2016"=>1,
  "Sat, 02 Apr 2016"=>1,
  "Sun, 03 Apr 2016"=>1
}
```

Comment: it's working fine ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example:

```
sample1 = [1,2,3,4]
sample2 = [5,6,7,8]

sample1.push(sample2)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```